# How to save files in Cherrypy

Tags: python, cherrypy

I'm trying to create a simple web application where a user can upload a file for my program to work with on the backend.

The application is going to run on a UNIX system.

How do I save their uploaded file locally (in the same directory) for my program to then work with?

```
class Root():

        @cherrypy.expose
        def index(self):

            return """
            <html><body>
              <center>
                <h2>Upload file</h2>
                <form action="upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                filename: <input type="file" name="myFile" /><br />
                <input type="submit" />
                </form>
              </center>
            </body></html>
            """
```

This example is from:
https://docs.cherrypy.org/en/latest/_modules/cherrypy/tutorial/tut09_files.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to save the file to your working directory, you will need to first `read()` the file and then `write()` it.

```
uploaded_file = myFile.file.read()
with open('saved_file_name.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(uploaded_file)
```